# Reverse Interpolation

Tags: audio, core-audio, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a class implementing an audio stream that can be read at varying speed (including reverse and fast varying / "scratching")... I use linear interpolation for the read part and everything works quite decently..

But now I want to implement writing to the stream at varying speed as well and that requires me to implement a kind of "reverse interpolation" i.e. Deduce the input sample vector Z that, interpolated with vector Y will produce the output X (which I'm trying to write)..

I've managed to do it for constant speeds, but generalising for varying speeds (e.g accelerating or decelerating) is proving more complicated..

I imagine this problem has been solved repeatedly, but I can't seem to find many clues online, so my specific question is if anyone has heard of this problem and can point me in the right direction (or, even better, show me a solution :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing your interpolating by using an FIR?

Answer (score 0):

I would not call it "reverse interpolation" as that does not exists (my first thought was you were talking about extrapolation!).  What you are doing is still simply interpolation, just at an uneven rate.

Interpolation: finding a value between known values
Extrapolation: finding a value beyond known values

Interpolating to/from constant rates is indeed much much simpler than the generic quest of "finding a value between known values".  I propose 2 solutions.

1) Interpolate to a significantly higher rate, and then just sub-sample to the nearest one (try adding dithering)

2) Solve the generic problem: for each point you need to use the neighboring N points and fit a order N-1 polynomial to them.

- N=2 would be linear and would add overtones (C0 continuity)
- N=3 could leave you with step changes at the halfway point between your source samples (perhaps worse overtones than N=2!)
- N=4 will get you C1 continuity (slope will match as you change to the next sample), surely enough for your application.

Let me explain that last one.

For each output sample use the 2 previous and 2 following input samples.  Call them S0 to S3 on a unit time scale (multiply by your sample period later), and you are interpolating from time 0 to 1.  Y is your output and Y' is the slope.

Y will be calculated from this polynomial and its differential (slope)

```
    Y(t) = At^3 + Bt^2 + Ct + D
    Y'(t) = 3At^2 + 2Bt + C
```

The constraints (the values and slope at the endpoints on either side)

```
    Y(0) = S1
    Y'(0) = (S2-S0)/2
    Y(1) = S2
    Y'(1) = (S3-S1)/2
```

Expanding the polynomial

```
    Y(0) = D
    Y'(0) = C
    Y(1) = A+B+C+D
    Y'(1) = 3A+2B+C
```

Plugging in the Samples

```
    D = S1
    C = (S2-S0)/2
    A + B = S2 - C - D
    3A+2B = (S3-S1)/2 - C
```

The last 2 are a system of equations that are easily solvable.  Subtract 2x the first from the second.

```
    3A+2B - 2(A+B)= (S3-S1)/2 - C - 2(S2 - C - D)
    A             = (S3-S1)/2 + C - 2(S2 - D)
```

Then B is

```
    B = S2 - A - C - D
```

Once you have A, B, C and D you can put in an time 't' in the polynomial to find a sample value between your known samples.

Repeat for every output sample, reuse A,B,C&D if the next output sample is still between the same 2 input samples. Calculating t each time is similar to Bresenham's line algorithm, you're just advancing by a different amount each time.